# (Why) Are Heartburn and Acid Stomach considered the same thing?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

In "1001 Easy Spanish Phrases," it says that "heartburn" is "agruras/acidez estomacal"

While it has been said that the way to a man's heart is through his stomach, is it really so that heartburn and acid stomach are the same thing?

Comment: Yes, but you should ask that in an English forum :) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heartburn

Comment: In English, they are two separate words, and I had no idea they referred to the same condition. IOW, in English "heartburn" is "heartburn" and "acid stomach" is "acid stomach" but in Spanish they both ("agruras" y "acidez estomacl") seem to equate to "heartburn"

Comment: The wikipedia page starts with: "Heartburn, also known as acid indigestion", so they are synonyms in English. Spanish has nothing to do with that fact.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the word "heartburn". What is the difference between both terms in English? BTW, an alternative term in Spanish for "acidez estomacal" is "reflujo". I had never heard "agruras" before.

Comment: @Yay In Chile, *reflujo* & *acidez estomacal* are utterly different things. :0

Comment: @Ustanak I'm afraid to ask but, what does *reflujo* mean in Chile then?

Comment: @Yay *reflujo* is an illness, chronic for most people.

Comment: I think heartburn is what people say they have as a symptom and acid reflux into the oesophagus is what the doctor tells you is your condition

Comment: @mdewey exactly, that's what the Wikipedia article says (second paragraph).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken (please correct me), in English _sífilis_ and _peste_ are considered the same thing ("_pox_"). If so, it would be an example of that words do not always coincide with those concepts.

Comment: Those look like Latin words to me, but the first makes me think of syphilis, which is a sexually transmitted disease, and the second puts me in the mind of pestilence, a general term for a disease.

Comment: Isn't this a question of biology, not of language?

Comment: Sorry for the strange example of "pox". What I was trying to say is that in all languages sometimes words encompass several concepts simultaneously (in this case diseases). Which is not to say you really think that the two _concepts_ are the same _thing_ although they say with the same word.

Comment: "Peste" is the black death or the plague. It can also be used to refer to any kind of plague or pestilence, but it is conventionally used to name the bubonic plague, specially when used with the determined article "la". Not to be confused with "pestilencia", which means stench or stink (n.). Pox is "viruela" or "varicela". I think those are also called differently in English (pox, chickenpox, small pox, etc.).

Comment: @Ustanak Interesting. I had always used and heard "reflujo" as a synonym for "acidez". I guess in Spain "reflujo" can be both the feeling and the illness.

Comment: @Yay I think that "ardor (de estómago)" is a better synonym of "acidez".

Comment: Note that "acidez" and "ardor" are intimatelly related: the techincall term for heartburn is "pirosis", defined as "a technical name for heartburn", while hearburn is "a burning sensation in the stomach, typically extending toward the esophagus, and sometimes associated with the eructation of an acid fluid; pyrosis."  http://www.thefreedictionary.com/pyrosis

Comment: @Yay Indeed what's called *reflujo* for us, it's what called this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gastroesophageal_reflux_disease

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has more to do with pathology than spanish.

Answer (score 2):

Well, they both are just your stomach acids that go too acid. Yes, you call both of them *Acidez*, but in English they are also synonyms.